# How to embed/display code in texmaker?

Tags: r, texmaker

I am new to texmaker. I have difficulty in displaying the codes and results I got from R in my texmaker document.

For example I have this results:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

How do I display that in texmaker that it looks like the one you are seeing? (indented, gray background, looks like a code from R).

What do I need to have?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to actually execute the `R`code? If so, you'll need to look to a package like `knitr` which can run `R` code embedded in  Tex documents.

Comment: not for now. I just need to display both the command and the results.

Answer (score 0):

Would the listings package (which supports R) achieve what you want?: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings

In LaTeX you can also just use the verb(atim) environment for fixed-width, not interpreted text:

```
/begin{verb}
    > R code goes here...
/end{verb}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display both the command and the results, then don't you need to execute the R code? (Unless you are planning to copy and paste the results...).

I would suggest checking out the `knitr` package.